# Excel IE Automation identifying a "css" element

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, ie-automation

Still plundering along scraping web sites, printing from web pages, etc. but ran into a snag I'm hoping someone can help me with. The pic below is shows the tab that I'd like to activate and I have the code to get me right there but can't activate the tab. While the last line of code will work on my desktop PC, I can't get it to work on my other PC's. I likely could juxtapose IE on the other PC's to make it work but I know that I'm just identifying the element wrong and if I did it correctly it should work all the time without having to mess with the IE settings.

A pic of the site with the "**Location Report**" tab is below
[image: Oasis Map Site]

Using Selenium on a different browser I was able to determine that the tab was identified as below::

```
css=#ext-gen42 .x-tab-strip-text
xpath=//a[@id='ext-gen42']/em/span/span
xpath=//div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a[2]/em/span/span
```

My code to get me to that point is here:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)
    Dim theEvent As Object
    htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
    Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
    htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
Sub Oasis_Test()
    LocnAddr = "1 park Ave"
    LocnBoro = "Manhattan"
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim htmlDoc As Object
    Dim Field1 As Object
    Dim Field2 As Object
    Dim Field3 As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://www.oasisnyc.net/map.aspx"
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))
    'ShowWindow IE.hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED   ' off for test purposes
    Set htmlDoc = IE.document
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Field1 = htmlDoc.getElementById("ext-comp-1076")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, Field1, "compositionstart")
    Field1.value = LocnAddr
    Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, Field1, "compositionend")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
    ' there's probably a better way to do this drop-down but this works
    Set Field2 = htmlDoc.getElementById("ext-comp-1078")
    Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, Field2, "compositionstart")
    Field2.value = LocnBoro
    Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, Field2, "compositionend")
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
    htmlDoc.getElementById("ext-gen118").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
    ' I don't get an error on the next line and it actually works on my desktop
    ' but can't get it to work anywhere else.
    htmlDoc.getElementById("ext-gen42").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
    htmlDoc.getElementById("ext-gen44").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
    htmlDoc.getElementById("ext-gen46").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
    htmlDoc.getElementById("ext-gen42").Click   '##### NG ######
End Sub
```

So my question is what is the correct way to identify that "ext-gen42" element so that I can click on or press it to have that tab display so that I can scrape the information off of it?.
I'm sure I'll run into more "css" elements (or whatever they are) as I continue so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Adding html as suggested]

Comment: I think your code based on this answer from me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294113/automate-ie-via-excel-to-fill-in-a-dropdown-and-continue/63299608#63299608 But you do some errors because you don't understand how the code works I think. E.g. your address field has no `compositionstart` and `compositionend` events.

Comment: Look at the screenshots in the linked answer and than look which events are availible for your needed elements. I havn't testet which events must be triggered to do what you want. But the tab has a `mousover` event and all tabs together have a `mousedown` event. I think you need both to switch the tab. Perhaps I find later time to have a better look.

Comment: Yes. I did use the code that you gave me in that other answer for a different site and I truly appreciate and learned a lot from it. I couldn't get that "boro" dropdown to work initially on this one so I tried your composition start/end and it did work. I just now replaced that with a {TAB} and it works without the comp start/end. Not sure why but I'm still learning. That "ext-gen42" was what was giving me problems with this code which is why I posted this question. Yu Zhou seems to have come up with a novel way of addressing it and gets me where I need to be and I'm thankful to him for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the click function can't work, you could try to change the class of the tabs and the class of the tab contents to active the **Location Report** tab.

You can change the **Location Report** tab class to active and hide the **Legend** tab content. Please try to replace the not working "click" part to this:

```
doc.getElementById("ext-comp-1065__ext-comp-1004").setAttribute "class", ""
doc.getElementById("ext-comp-1065__locationReport").setAttribute "class", "x-tab-strip-active"
doc.getElementById("ext-comp-1004").setAttribute "class", "x-panel x-panel-noborder x-hide-display"
doc.getElementById("locationReport").setAttribute "class", "x-panel x-panel-noborder"
```

You could check the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF7QJ.jpg) in IE.