# Use VB script to automate click(expanding) plus sign within internet explorer

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Using a VB script (via Excel), I am working on automating some data entry into an IE web page.  I have successfully been able to use ".getElementById("WhateverID").Click" in most instances.  However, there is a plus sign button that has not been responding to the Click command.  Here is what the button ("btnAddAction") looks like:
[Add Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGSed.png)

Upon clicking the Add Action button, two new buttons appear ("btnSaveAction" and "btnCancelAction"):
[Save Action & Cancel Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpa3K.png)

Any suggestions on how to get this Add Action button to respond with this code:
objIE.document.getElementById("btnAddAction").Click

Here is the web inspection code:

```
<section class="placement-update" id="DecisionUpdate">
    <div style="display: block;">
        <nav class="navbar navheading blueBar">
            <h5 class="heading"> Decision Update</h5>
            <div class="ml-auto crd_save">
                <img tabindex="-32768" class="pointer" id="btnSaveAction" style="display: inline;" src="/images/save.svg">
            </div>

            <div class="edit">
                    <img tabindex="-32768" class="pointer" id="btnAddAction" style="display: none;" src="/images/add.svg">
                <img tabindex="-32768" class="pointer" id="btnCancelAction" style="display: inline;" src="/images/cancel.svg">
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: VBA and VBScript are different, removed the VBScript tag.

Comment: There is a very similar question dealing with using VB to get an element by ID, and "clicking" in excel. The approved answer might give you some direction.

Comment: Is there any error when you click the button? Is the button in an iframe? You can also check if there's any onclick function in the `btnAddAction` button. If so, you can also fire the onclick function directly to get the button responding.

Comment: There is no debug error with:  objIE.document.getElementById("btnAddAction").Click       However, the visible result of the click action is not happening.  Upon clicking, a number of editable fields become available allowing for the subsequent clicking of the Save Action or Cancel Action buttons.

Comment: I suggest you try to change the classes of the elements to make them available to simulate the click function. You can refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677723/excel-ie-automation-identifying-a-css-element/63680823#63680823) in this thread which uses the same idea. I think you'll know how to try after referring to it.