# Using VBA to Webscrape a WebSite with Login Page

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, password-protection

The current Code in VBA is

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub login ()
 Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 Set i =New InternetExplorer
 i.Visible=True
 i.navigate ("https://insertconfidentialwebsitehere")
 Do while i.readystate <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Loop
 Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Set idoc=i.document
 Idoc.all.USER.Value="username"
 idoc.all.password.value="password"
 End Sub
```

The website does load when I run but I get `Automation error 440` and the username and password do not show up when I run the command.
I checked through the reference after inspecting element which is correct.
It is `USER` and `PASSWORD`.
I'm not sure why those values are not filled in with the given code.

I have also made VBS code for this application and VBS works great with Send Keys. If the above code has nothing wrong with it could you find a way to implement VBS send keys with the VBA and maybe that would work?

I don't know why using `idoc.all` is not loading my credentials.

Comment: Since the address of the site seems to be a big secret ... I suppose the input fields are linked to events you have to trigger. Please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647587/excel-vba-to-login-to-website-and-grab-tr-td-elements/64649318#64649318