# click button on website via VBA - problem

Tags: html, excel, vba, click

I have a problem with this site: https://portale.fnomceo.it/cerca-prof/index.php
If i put manually the data all is ok. the website function.
If I put the data trough VBA the site don't function and answer error.
why?
thank in advance
Nic

Comment: Please update your question with your VBA code stating the line at which the error occurs as well as the error number and description.

Comment: The input boxes `Data nascita (gg/mm/aaaa)` and `Ordine della provincia di` have events. I think, the right ones must be triggered. Look here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294113/automate-ie-via-excel-to-fill-in-a-dropdown-and-continue/63299608#63299608