# Posting MRN data into https://www.douane.gouv.fr/enveloppe/en/enveloppe/creer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a task to add data to the French governments website for export truck movements to the UK.
The site is https://www.douane.gouv.fr/enveloppe/en/enveloppe/creer
I have all the data in an Excel Spreadsheet but I think the website used KeyDown and Keypress events to accept the information.  When I add the data into the site the response is "Field cannot be empty" even though I can see the data is in the form field. This is my VBA test code

```
Sub postData()

'references Microsoft HTML Object Library and the Microsoft Internet Controls.

    Dim IE As Object
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate ("https://www.douane.gouv.fr/enveloppe/en/enveloppe/creer")
    
    'Wait for IE to settle
    Do While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set doc = IE.document
    
    For f = 1 To 2
    
        
        Set le_element = doc.getElementsByClassName("form-control input-declaration")
        
        If le_element.Length > 0 Then
            le_element(f - 1).Value = "23NLLIWZQGAK55WD50"
            
            Set evt = doc.createEvent("keyboardevent")
            evt.initEvent "keyDown", True, False
            le_element(f - 1).dispatchEvent evt
        End If
     
        Set Button = doc.getElementsByClassName("bouton-action btn-add-declaration")
                
        If Button.Length > 0 Then
            Button(0).Click
        End If
        
        While IE.Busy
          DoEvents
          Set doc = IE.document
          Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Wend
        
        Set doc = IE.document
     
    Next f
    
    'Debug.Print "Ret = " & ret
    
    
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have tried a number of ways to get the data into the field but it appears to need a keypress for each character.  I can easily loop through the data a character at a time but cannot figure out how to trigger a keypress event in Excel VBA as I go

Comment: My advice is to stop using IE but the linked posting is for a little more complex page with evnets to fire. You can look there how it works.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294113/automate-ie-via-excel-to-fill-in-a-dropdown-and-continue/63299608#63299608