How do I Choose from this webpage dropdown in IE using VBA
I am trying to scrape a website using VBA and I cant seem to figure out how to select from the choices in a dropdown. It seems like the Options are hidden and only show in the HTML code one they are chosen. I cant share the website since it contains HIPPA protected info but here is the HTML code for the Dropdown:
<span tabindex="0" class="e-input-group e-control-wrapper e-ddl e-lib e-keyboard" 
role="listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="ProviderId_hidden" 
aria-activedescendant="null" aria-owns="ProviderId_options" 
style="width: 100%;" ejs-for="true" value="">
<select name="ProviderId" tabindex="-1" class="e-ddl-hidden" id="ProviderId_hidden" aria-hidden="true"></select>
<input tabindex="-1" class="e-control e-dropdownlist e-lib e-input"
 id="ProviderId" role="textbox" type="text" readonly="" 
  placeholder="Select Provider Id" value="" ejs-for="true" 
  aria-placeholder="Select Provider Id">
<span class="e-input-group-icon e-ddl-icon e-search-icon"></span></span>

<script>var DropDownListpw4kya4qs1g=new ejs.dropdowns.DropDownList({
  "dataSource": ejs.data.DataUtil.parse.isJson([
  {
    "Id": "203583195001",
    "Name": "BEECHER MANOR NURSG AND RHB CT - XXXXXXXX5001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "831482996001",
    "Name": "BURBANK REHABILITATION CENTER - XXXXXXXX6001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "320039566001",
    "Name": "CHATEAU NURSING AND REHAB - XXXXXXXX6001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "270991423001",
    "Name": "COUNTRYSIDE NRSG AND REHAB CTR - XXXXXXXX3001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "872856324001",
    "Name": "CRESTWOOD REHABILITATION CENTE - XXXXXXXX4001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "471130053001",
    "Name": "ESTATES OF HYDE PARK - XXXXXXXX3001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "874825795001",
    "Name": "FARMINGTON VILLAGE NURSING AND - XXXXXXXX5001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "364269374002",
    "Name": "GRASMERE PLACE - XXXXXXXX4002"
  },
  {
    "Id": "300124869001",
    "Name": "LAKEWOOD NURSING AND REHAB CTR - XXXXXXXX9001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "383663760001",
    "Name": "LEMONT NURSING AND REHAB CTR - XXXXXXXX0001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "863403499001",
    "Name": "LINCOLN VILLAGE HEALTHCARE - XXXXXXXX9001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "810583511001",
    "Name": "PRAIRIE MANOR NURSING REHAB - XXXXXXXX1001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "364149930001",
    "Name": "PRAIRIE VLG HEALTHCARE CTR INC - XXXXXXXX0001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "203283565001",
    "Name": "RAINBOW BEACH CARE CENTER - XXXXXXXX5001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "933179830001",
    "Name": "RENWICK NURSING AND REHAB - XXXXXXXX0001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "474398932001",
    "Name": "RUSHVILLE NURSING & REHABILITA - XXXXXXXX2001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "831201361001",
    "Name": "SOUTH HOLLAND MANOR HLTH REHAB - XXXXXXXX1001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "933156231001",
    "Name": "SOUTH SHORE REHABILITATION - XXXXXXXX1001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "205897291001",
    "Name": "SOUTH SUBURBAN REHAB CENTER - XXXXXXXX1001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "464731186001",
    "Name": "ST JAMES WELLNESS REHAB VILLAS - XXXXXXXX6001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "473964105001",
    "Name": "SYMPHONY OF SOUTH SHORE - XXXXXXXX5001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "364186824001",
    "Name": "TIMBERPOINT HEALTHCARE CENTER - XXXXXXXX4001"
  },
  {
    "Id": "831201262001",
    "Name": "WESTMONT MANOR HLTH AND REHAB - XXXXXXXX2001"
  }
]),
  "enableRtl": false,
  "fields": {
    "text": "Name",
    "value": "Id"
  },
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "ProviderId"
  },
  "ignoreAccent": false,
  "placeholder": "Select Provider Id",
  "popupHeight": "200px",
  "zIndex": 1000.0,
  "change": LoadNpi
});
DropDownListpw4kya4qs1g.appendTo("#ProviderId"); 
var DropDownListoneh5stfh2f=new ejs.dropdowns.DropDownList({
  "dataSource": ejs.data.DataUtil.parse.isJson([]),
  "enableRtl": false,
  "fields": {
    "text": "Name",
    "value": "Id"
  },
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "NPI"
  },
  "ignoreAccent": false,
  "placeholder": "Select NPI",
  "popupHeight": "200px",
  "zIndex": 1000.0
});
DropDownListoneh5stfh2f.appendTo("#NPI"); 
var DatePickerxxius4aizhq=new ejs.calendars.DatePicker({
  "enableRtl": false,
  "format": "MM/dd/yyyy",
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "StartDate"
  },
  "value": "2024-05-23T15:31:51.6983766-05:00",
  "blur": FormatBeginDate,
  "focus": SelectBeginDate
});
DatePickerxxius4aizhq.appendTo("#StartDate"); 
var DatePickeraydhn32jufj=new ejs.calendars.DatePicker({
  "enableRtl": false,
  "format": "MM/dd/yyyy",
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "EndDate"
  },
  "value": "2024-05-23T15:31:51.6983766-05:00",
  "change": FormatEndDate,
  "focus": SelectEndDate
});
DatePickeraydhn32jufj.appendTo("#EndDate"); 
var TextBoxezsdehjikoe=new ejs.inputs.TextBox({
  "enableRtl": false,
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "RecipientNumber"
  },
  "placeholder": "Recipient Number"
});
TextBoxezsdehjikoe.appendTo("#RecipientNumber"); 
var TextBoxin4ilijizad=new ejs.inputs.TextBox({
  "enableRtl": false,
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "Ssn"
  },
  "placeholder": "SSN"
});
TextBoxin4ilijizad.appendTo("#Ssn"); 
var TextBoxvcw4dcs0mfv=new ejs.inputs.TextBox({
  "enableRtl": false,
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "FirstName"
  },
  "placeholder": "First Name"
});
TextBoxvcw4dcs0mfv.appendTo("#FirstName"); 
var TextBoxp23gp0he5wn=new ejs.inputs.TextBox({
  "enableRtl": false,
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "LastName"
  },
  "placeholder": "Last Name"
});
TextBoxp23gp0he5wn.appendTo("#LastName"); 
var TextBoxqvgwqjwoodb=new ejs.inputs.TextBox({
  "enableRtl": false,
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "DateOfBirth"
  },
  "placeholder": "MM/DD/YYYY"
});
TextBoxqvgwqjwoodb.appendTo("#DateOfBirth"); 
var TextBoxwytxc5zn1ud=new ejs.inputs.TextBox({
  "enableRtl": false,
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "Zip"
  },
  "placeholder": "Zip Code"
});
TextBoxwytxc5zn1ud.appendTo("#Zip"); 
var DropDownListgbvudpqfljg=new ejs.dropdowns.DropDownList({
  "dataSource": ejs.data.DataUtil.parse.isJson([
  {
    "Id": "010",
    "Name": "ADAMS-010"
  },
  {
    "Id": "011",
    "Name": "ALEXANDER-011"
  },
  {
    "Id": "019",
    "Name": "CHAMPAIGN-019"
  },
  {
    "Id": "020",
    "Name": "CHRISTIAN-020"
  },
  {
    "Id": "021",
    "Name": "CLARK-021"
  },
  {
    "Id": "022",
    "Name": "CLAY-022"
  },
  {
    "Id": "023",
    "Name": "CLINTON-023"
  },
  {
    "Id": "024",
    "Name": "COLES-024"
  },
  {
    "Id": "200",
    "Name": "COOK-200"
  },
  {
    "Id": "025",
    "Name": "CRAWFORD-025"
  },
  {
    "Id": "026",
    "Name": "CUMBERLAND-026"
  },
  {
    "Id": "027",
    "Name": "DEKALB-027"
  },
  {
    "Id": "028",
    "Name": "DEWIT-028"
  },
  {
    "Id": "029",
    "Name": "DOUGLAS-029"
  },
  {
    "Id": "030",
    "Name": "DUPAGE-030"
  },
  {
    "Id": "031",
    "Name": "EDGAR-031"
  },
  {
    "Id": "032",
    "Name": "EDWARDS-032"
  },
  {
    "Id": "033",
    "Name": "EFFINGHAM-033"
  },
  {
    "Id": "208",
    "Name": "ENGLEWOOD-208"
  },
  {
    "Id": "034",
    "Name": "FAYETTE-034"
  },
  {
    "Id": "035",
    "Name": "FORD-035"
  },
  {
    "Id": "036",
    "Name": "FRANKLIN-036"
  },
  {
    "Id": "037",
    "Name": "FULTON-037"
  },
  {
    "Id": "038",
    "Name": "GALLATIN-038"
  },
  {
    "Id": "215",
    "Name": "GARFIELD-215"
  },
  {
    "Id": "039",
    "Name": "GREENE-039"
  },
  {
    "Id": "040",
    "Name": "GRUNDY-040"
  },
  {
    "Id": "041",
    "Name": "HAMILTON-041"
  },
  {
    "Id": "042",
    "Name": "HANCOCK-042"
  },
  {
    "Id": "043",
    "Name": "HARDIN-043"
  },
  {
    "Id": "044",
    "Name": "HENDERSON-044"
  },
  {
    "Id": "045",
    "Name": "HENRY-045"
  },
  {
    "Id": "231",
    "Name": "HUMBOLDTPARK-231"
  },
  {
    "Id": "046",
    "Name": "IROQUOIS-046"
  },
  {
    "Id": "047",
    "Name": "JACKSON-047"
  },
  {
    "Id": "048",
    "Name": "JASPER-048"
  },
  {
    "Id": "049",
    "Name": "JEFFERSON-049"
  },
  {
    "Id": "050",
    "Name": "JERSEY-050"
  },
  {
    "Id": "051",
    "Name": "JODAVIES-051"
  },
  {
    "Id": "052",
    "Name": "JOHNSON-052"
  },
  {
    "Id": "053",
    "Name": "KANE-053"
  },
  {
    "Id": "114",
    "Name": "KANE/ELGIN-114"
  },
  {
    "Id": "054",
    "Name": "KANKAKEE-054"
  },
  {
    "Id": "055",
    "Name": "KENDALL-055"
  },
  {
    "Id": "206",
    "Name": "KENWOOD-206"
  },
  {
    "Id": "056",
    "Name": "KNOX-056"
  },
  {
    "Id": "057",
    "Name": "LAKE-057"
  },
  {
    "Id": "058",
    "Name": "LASALLE-058"
  },
  {
    "Id": "059",
    "Name": "LAWRENCE-059"
  },
  {
    "Id": "060",
    "Name": "LEE-060"
  },
  {
    "Id": "061",
    "Name": "LIVINGSTON-061"
  },
  {
    "Id": "062",
    "Name": "LOGAN-062"
  },
  {
    "Id": "228",
    "Name": "LOWER NORTH CHICAGO-228"
  },
  {
    "Id": "063",
    "Name": "MACON-063"
  },
  {
    "Id": "064",
    "Name": "MACOUPIN-064"
  },
  {
    "Id": "115",
    "Name": "MADISON-EASTALTON-115"
  },
  {
    "Id": "065",
    "Name": "MADISON/GRANITECITY-065"
  },
  {
    "Id": "066",
    "Name": "MARION-066"
  },
  {
    "Id": "067",
    "Name": "MARSHALL-067"
  },
  {
    "Id": "068",
    "Name": "MASON-068"
  },
  {
    "Id": "069",
    "Name": "MASSAC-069"
  },
  {
    "Id": "070",
    "Name": "MCDONOUGH-070"
  },
  {
    "Id": "071",
    "Name": "MCHENRY-071"
  },
  {
    "Id": "072",
    "Name": "MCLEAN-072"
  },
  {
    "Id": "073",
    "Name": "MENARD-073"
  },
  {
    "Id": "074",
    "Name": "MERCER-074"
  },
  {
    "Id": "202",
    "Name": "MICHIGAN-202"
  },
  {
    "Id": "075",
    "Name": "MONROE-075"
  },
  {
    "Id": "076",
    "Name": "MONTGOMERY-076"
  },
  {
    "Id": "077",
    "Name": "MORGAN-077"
  },
  {
    "Id": "078",
    "Name": "MOULTRIE-078"
  },
  {
    "Id": "233",
    "Name": "NORTHERN-233"
  },
  {
    "Id": "237",
    "Name": "NORTHWEST-237"
  },
  {
    "Id": "203",
    "Name": "OAKLAND-203"
  },
  {
    "Id": "079",
    "Name": "OGLE-079"
  },
  {
    "Id": "205",
    "Name": "PARKMANOR-205"
  },
  {
    "Id": "080",
    "Name": "PEORIA-080"
  },
  {
    "Id": "081",
    "Name": "PERRY-081"
  },
  {
    "Id": "235",
    "Name": "PERSHING-235"
  },
  {
    "Id": "082",
    "Name": "PIATT-082"
  },
  {
    "Id": "083",
    "Name": "PIKE-083"
  },
  {
    "Id": "084",
    "Name": "POPE-084"
  },
  {
    "Id": "085",
    "Name": "PULASKI-085"
  },
  {
    "Id": "086",
    "Name": "PUTNAM-086"
  },
  {
    "Id": "087",
    "Name": "RANDOLPH-087"
  },
  {
    "Id": "088",
    "Name": "RICHLAND-088"
  },
  {
    "Id": "089",
    "Name": "ROCKISLAND-089"
  },
  {
    "Id": "236",
    "Name": "ROSELAND-236"
  },
  {
    "Id": "090",
    "Name": "SALINE-090"
  },
  {
    "Id": "091",
    "Name": "SANGAMON-091"
  },
  {
    "Id": "092",
    "Name": "SCHUYLER-092"
  },
  {
    "Id": "093",
    "Name": "SCOTT-093"
  },
  {
    "Id": "094",
    "Name": "SHELBY-094"
  },
  {
    "Id": "218",
    "Name": "SOUTHEAST-218"
  },
  {
    "Id": "226",
    "Name": "SOUTHSUBURBANCHICAGO-226"
  },
  {
    "Id": "112",
    "Name": "ST.CLAIR/BELLEVILLE-112"
  },
  {
    "Id": "095",
    "Name": "STARK-095"
  },
  {
    "Id": "096",
    "Name": "STCLAIR-096"
  },
  {
    "Id": "111",
    "Name": "STCLAIR/EASTSTLOUIS-111"
  },
  {
    "Id": "097",
    "Name": "STEPHENSON-097"
  },
  {
    "Id": "098",
    "Name": "TAZWELL-098"
  },
  {
    "Id": "099",
    "Name": "UNION-099"
  },
  {
    "Id": "204",
    "Name": "UPTOWN-204"
  },
  {
    "Id": "100",
    "Name": "VERMILION-100"
  },
  {
    "Id": "101",
    "Name": "WABASH-101"
  },
  {
    "Id": "102",
    "Name": "WARREN-102"
  },
  {
    "Id": "103",
    "Name": "WASHINGTON-103"
  },
  {
    "Id": "104",
    "Name": "WAYNE-104"
  },
  {
    "Id": "201",
    "Name": "WESTERN-201"
  },
  {
    "Id": "229",
    "Name": "WESTERNSUBURBANCHICAGO-229"
  },
  {
    "Id": "105",
    "Name": "WHITE-105"
  },
  {
    "Id": "106",
    "Name": "WHITESIDE-106"
  },
  {
    "Id": "217",
    "Name": "WICKERPARK-217"
  },
  {
    "Id": "107",
    "Name": "WILL-107"
  },
  {
    "Id": "108",
    "Name": "WILLIAMSON-108"
  },
  {
    "Id": "109",
    "Name": "WINNEBAGO-109"
  },
  {
    "Id": "110",
    "Name": "WOODFORD-110"
  },
  {
    "Id": "212",
    "Name": "WOODLAWN-212"
  }
]),
  "enableRtl": false,
  "fields": {
    "text": "Name",
    "value": "Id"
  },
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "CountyId"
  },
  "ignoreAccent": false,
  "placeholder": "Select a County",
  "popupHeight": "200px",
  "value": 0,
  "zIndex": 1000.0
});
DropDownListgbvudpqfljg.appendTo("#CountyId"); 
var CheckBox04mk1kbgp04=new ejs.buttons.CheckBox({
  "cssClass": "form-control",
  "enablePersistence": false,
  "enableRtl": false,
  "htmlAttributes": {
    "ejs-for": "true",
    "id": "PendingDenied",
    "type": "checkbox"
  },
  "name": "PendingDenied",
  "value": "true"
});
CheckBox04mk1kbgp04.appendTo("#PendingDenied"); 
</script>

I tried SelectedIndex and getelementbyid("ProviderID").options and nothing happens. As if the options don't exists until one of them is chosen. How do I choose one of teh options from this dropdown with VBA?

IE should no longer be used, it is outdated. Your problem is almost certainly related to events being triggered. In the past I have described here in great detail how events can be found and triggered with VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294113/automate-ie-via-excel-to-fill-in-a-dropdown-and-continue/63299608#63299608
