Downloading multiple Excel files from webpage with VBA
As the title suggests I'd like to download multiple Excel's from the following site:
https://akk.hu/statistics/yields-indices-market-turnover/zero-coupon-yields
There is an Excel report button, which will download an excel for the given Date Range, however, no matter what I set for the start or end date, the site has a maximum range of 7 days. What I'd like to do, is to download Excel sheets for a whole year, so in my imagination I'd like to have a VBA code which will step the Date Range by seven days and then download the Excel file for given period.
So far I haven't achieved that much, my code only looks like this:
Sub adatgyujto()

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "https://akk.hu/statisztika/hozamok-indexek-forgalmi-adatok/zero-kupon-hozamok"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub

I also tried to get the html code for the Date Range and download buttons, but they look strange to me.
The HTML code for the download button:
<span class="custom-menubar-menuitem-caption"><span class="v-icon Akk-Icons">?</span></span>


For your goal, a number of events must be triggered. As the IE is outdated, nobody will put any more energy into a solution. Here you can see how to work with events in IE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294113/automate-ie-via-excel-to-fill-in-a-dropdown-and-continue/63299608#63299608 It looks like browser automation is the way to go. This could be done with SeleniumBasic. I don't know how events can be handled there. Here you can see how SeleniumBasic can be made to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps#57224810

I see, thank you! Yeah I figured IE wouldn't be the best to work with, however that is what I started with...
